# $_SESSION doesn't work. xampp php7

Tags: php, html, session, xampp

I have tried to make site with registrations on xammp but it looks like that $_SESSION doesn't work. I have session_start(); on every document. Here are my files. I hope you can help me :) <3

I also have some index.php in which there are only 2 redirecting buttons to register.php and login.php(it is not complete)

This is my register.php:

```
<?php
session_start();

$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "login");

if(isset($_POST['reg_btn'])) {
$username  = $_POST['username'];  //here I also tried with $_SESSION but it doesn't work
$email = $_POST['email'];         //
$password = $_POST['password'];   //
$password2 = $_POST['password2']; //

    if ($password == $password2){
        $password = md5($password);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users(username, email, password) VALUES('$username', '$email', '$password')";
        mysqli_query($db, $sql);
        $_SESSION['message'] = "You are logged in!";
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        header("location:home.php");
    }else{
        $_SESSION['message'] = "The passwords doesn't match!";
    }
}
?>

<html>
<head>
<title>Login Page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="header"> 
    <h1>Register</h1>
</div>
<div id="frm"> 
<form action="register.php" method="POST">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><label>Email:</label></td>
        <td><input type="email" name="email" class="textInput" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label>Username:</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="username" class="textInput" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label>Password:</label></td>
        <td><input type="password" name="password"     class="textInput"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label>Password Confirmation:</label></td>
        <td><input type="password" name="password2" class="textInput"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="submit" name="reg_btn" value="Register"/>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my home.php where i want my session variables to be displayed:

```
<?php 
session_start();

?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Home Page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="header"> 
    <h1>Welcome <?php echo ",".$_SESSION['username'];?></h1>
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors? you might also want to consider using password_hash function to encrypt your password

Comment: Try `<?php session_start(); $_SESSION['foo'] = 'bar';` in one document, and then in another: `<?php session_start(); var_dump($_SESSION);` to see if a value persists.

Comment: (You also may want to consider using prepared queries.)

Comment: I could likely hijack another users' session/account, by using a previously used username.

Comment: @chinloyal No, I'm not getting errors. This "password = md5($password);" is password hash isn't it?

Comment: @Progrock I tried and session is working.

Comment: @BeckMega There's a more secure way to hash passwords: `password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);`

Comment: Did you just switch over to php7 with xampp, coming from php5?

Comment: @chinloyal Thank You! But I still have my problem.

Comment: @chinloyal No. When i installed xammp the php version was 7

Comment: Try using these file settings in your php.ini from this link https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/php-7-session-start-not-working/211635/2

Comment: If you tested and session IS working, then what is the problem?

Comment: @Progrock When i test on another files session id working. But when i try on mine files - it isn't.

Comment: And it doesn't work in the code you've posted?  If you set a session variable on register.php and then do a var_dump($_SESSION) in home.php do you get anything?  Same domain and protocol?

Comment: @Progrock
Ouch. I get: 
array(5) { ["name"]=> string(4) "sami" ["username"]=> string(0) "" ["test"]=> string(4) "sami" ["message"]=> string(18) "You are logged in!" ["foo"]=> string(3) "bar" } Your var is sami

PS. sami was my test session variable. But still there isn't username variable.

Comment: Okay, so is your register.php script doing the redirect after the insert?  Perhaps $_SESSION['username'] never gets set.  Though you do appear to have a message that appears as if you did get to that part of your code.

Comment: When I cleared the session it works!
Thank You for all the help1!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I clear the session with session_unset(); it works!
Thanks for the help =)

Answer (score 0):

check the files with another editor, or copy past the code to new files. I had such issue before and it happened because my file included a character before the opening php tag.